# Do banks provide any developer api for app use?

Tags: android, api, banking

I want to know if there is any banks that provide an api for developers (specifically android) so they can have users enter their account info (maybe just the username and not password) and then the api can retrieve the account balance from the account. I think it could be safe since its just reading and not writing.

Is there anyone who does this for free?

Facebook/twitter/tumbler does this which allows other sites to integrate this functionality in their apps, so I want to know if banks do this too.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: I really doubt you'd find a bank that did-  its a massive security and liability risk.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying it's safe, it's leak the security if we have the option of getting accounts info by the using only account number.

As per my knowledge there is no such api for providing bank user details. Even bank is also saying that if some third person asking bank detail never give to them,

And bank always loyal to hide the information of their customers, it's integrity of bank rules.

Comment: This service restricted most of the country, in India its also not working. And as per my knowledge mint not work on bank money, it convert bank money to mint money

Comment: What about the post below, that seems to get bank transactions?

Comment: All these have their own limitations.

Answer (score 0):

[Mint](http://mint.com) was a pretty face on [Yodlee](http://www.yodlee.com), but [Intut changed that when they purchased them](http://investorjunkie.com/32242/yodlee-moneycenter-review/) in 2011. Yodlee has a [ruby api](https://github.com/aasmith/yodlee). A sample of its use is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'yodlee'

# Create some credentials to login with.
cred = Yodlee::Credentials.new
cred.username = 'bob'
cred.password = 'weak'

# The word the remote system stores and shows back to you to prove
# they really are Yodlee.
cred.expectation = 'roflcopter'

# An array of questions and answers. Yodlee expects you to answer
# three of thirty defined in Yodlee::Credentials::QUESTIONS.
cred.answers = [[Yodlee::Credentials::QUESTIONS[1], "The Queen"], [...]]

# That's enough credentials. Create a connection.
conn = Yodlee::Connection.new(cred)

# Connect, and get an account list.
conn.accounts.each do |account|
  puts account.institute_name, account.name, account.current_balance

  # grab a handy list of transactions. Parseable as CSV.
  puts account.simple_transactions

  # Next line needs johnson.
  # p account.transactions

  # take a look in account.account_info for a hash of useful stuff.
  # available keys vary by account type and institute.
end

# Should look something like this:

First Bank of Excess
Checking
$123.45
[...some csv...]
First Bank of Mattress
Savings
$1,234.56
[...more csv!...]
```

Hope that helps. If you need further information, do leave a comment.

Comment: So to use this practically, one would need to make a yodlee account (not free i think), and enter their bank account in it, then have a ruby server, and have the android query the ruby page with the credentials, then the ruby code would query the yodlee page with the credentials from android, and get back the account balance?